# CUDA: Thread-block Level Broadcast on K40 using Shuffle instrutions

Tags: cuda, kepler

`indirectJ2[MAX_SUPER_SIZE]` is a shared array.

My cuda device kernel contains following statement (executed by all threads in the thread block):

`int nnz_col = indirectJ2[MAX_SUPER_SIZE - 1];`

I suspect this would cause bank conflicts.

Is there any way I can implement the above  **Thread-block level broadcast** efficiently using new shuffle instructions for the kepler GPUs? I understand how it works at warp level. Other solutions, which are beyond shuffle instruction (for instance use of CUB etc.), are also welcome.

Answer (score 2):

There is no bank conflict for that line of code on K40.  Shared memory accesses already offer a broadcast mechanism.  Quoting from the [programming guide](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#shared-memory-3-0)

> "A shared memory request for a warp does not generate a bank conflict between two threads that access any sub-word within the same 32-bit word or within two 32-bit words whose indices i and j are in the same 64-word aligned segment (i.e., a segment whose first index is a multiple of 64) and such that j=i+32 (even though the addresses of the two sub-words fall in the same bank): In that case, for read accesses, **the 32-bit words are broadcast to the requesting threads** "

There is no such concept as shared memory bank conflicts at the threadblock level.  Bank conflicts only pertain to the access pattern generated by the shared memory request emanating from a single warp, for a single instruction in that warp.

If you like, you can write a simple test kernel and use [profiler metrics](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/profiler-users-guide/index.html#metrics-reference) (e.g. `shared_replay_overhead`) to test for shared memory bank conflicts.

Warp shuffle mechanisms do not extend beyond a single warp; therefore there is no short shuffle-only sequence that can broadcast a single quantity to multiple warps in a threadblock.  Shared memory *can* be used to provide direct access to a single quantity to all threads in a warp; you are already doing that.

global memory, `__constant__` memory, and kernel parameters can also all be used to "broadcast" the same value to all threads in a threadblock.